# Problem to deploy a netcore Web Api in Windows Server IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I'm strugguling to deploy a netcore 3.1 web api in an IIS inside a windows Server, I already tried a lot of tutorials that give some steps like this one https://codingsonata.com/deploy-asp-net-core-web-api-on-iis/ , but I'm always getting a error.
Now that is what I see:

[image]

Does anyone knows what I could try to fix it? I already tried a lot of things, change things in the webconfig, I activated everything in the Windows features but I always get this. I already spent a lot of time on it and without success. :/

Comment: If check whether you have web.config file, and you can change stdoutLogEnabled property value to “true”. Then you can check the error message.

Comment: You also can check the EventViewer log, it might help you. Pls update your post after you have checked the logs.

Comment: A Web API app has no visual pages to be displayed, so 403.14 is perfectly normal. To test your REST API, use tools like Postman. You are not the first one to ask such questions, and won't be the last to misunderstand REST API concepts either.

Comment: I know the concepts of REST API @LexLi, that is not the problem, I tried to access the direct route by postman or even calling the full route for a simple get that I added that should show a text and they didn't work.

Comment: I will try this @JasonPan, I had tried before but it was not saving the logs, but I will try from the eventviewer to see if I find something and I will add here.
Thanks.

Comment: Then let FRT reveal more to you about those 403.14 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis